# Laravel 4 pagination links ignore existing GET parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a search in Laravel 4. After search for sh my url is this:

```
http://localhost/musiter/product/search-products/24?query=sh
```

I also have pagination there, but the pagination for the second link for example is:

```
http://localhost/musiter/product/search-products/24?page=2
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost/musiter/product/search-products/24?query=sh&page=2
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're looking for is:

```
$paginator->appends(['query' => $value])->links();
```

---

You can add to the query string of pagination links using the appends method on the Paginator:

```
<?php echo $users->appends(array('sort' => 'votes'))->links(); ?>
```

This will generate URLs that look something like this:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=votes
```

If you wish to append a "hash fragment" to the paginator's URLs, you may use the fragment method:

```
<?php echo $users->fragment('foo')->links(); ?>
```

This method call will generate URLs that look something like this:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2#foo
```

You can also check [Laravel documentation].[1](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links)

Comment: That works, thanks! will accept as soon as it lets me.